# How to remove default entity_id sorting in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, admin, frontend, sorting

I need to remove the default entity_id sorting from category product collection and add position sorting.

here i try using the below method

```
> $cp = $category->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
> $cp->getSelect()->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::ORDER);
> $cp->addAttributeToSort('position');
```

but the entity_id sorting was not remove
also print the query

> SELECT `e`.*, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position` FROM
> `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`  INNER JOIN
> `catalog_category_product_index_store1` AS `cat_index` ON
> cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=1 AND
> cat_index.category_id=553 ORDER BY `cat_index`.`position` ASC,
> `e`.`entity_id` DESC

can any one guide me that how to remove the entity id sorting